# SLES 10 - repositories?

Tags: repository, sles

Can somebody help with adding a repo for SuSE Linux Enteprise Edition 10 SP3?

First - can't find any "official" repos. Found a few repos for openSUSE and few other - but every time I try them I get this error (using YaST2):

```
Unable to create installation source  

'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE%3a/Tools/SLE_10/'. 

Unknown source type for http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE%3a/Tools/SLE_10/
```

I also get the same with other repos...

Answer (score 2):

Given that's a discontinued release I have a feeling you're going to be out of luck, http://en.opensuse.org/Mirrors_discontinued_releases#openSUSE_10.3.

I did find this supposed repo that looks to be what you want:

- http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/linux/opensuse/discontinued/distribution/10.3/repo/oss/suse/i586/

If you back up the URL you'll get to this level which contains all the SLES that have been:

- http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/linux/opensuse/discontinued/distribution/

I would seriously consider mirroring this if you think you'll need it for any length of time. You should be able to use a tool such as `rsync` to do this if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but get same error: `Unable to create installation source from URL 'http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/linux/opensuse/discontinued/distribution/10.3/repo/oss/suse/i586'. 
Details:                                                 
Unknown source type for http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/linux/opensuse/discontinued/distribution/10.3/repo/oss/suse/i586` May I enter wrong data? Here is screenshot: [link](http://rtfm.co.ua/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/repo_add.png)

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's a fully functional mirror, it's a directory with the contents of packages (RPMs) and some other ancillary files that were included in the 10.3 release. I don't work with SuSE  so unless anyone else comes along, this might likely be the end of the line. To pursue it further you'll have to dig in and see what YaST is expecting and see if you can't pacify it by manually creating missing files or what not.